# Convert a list from ord into a List

Tags: python, list, input, binary

I would like to convert what is given from `bin` into a list.

What I have:

```
x = input()
for y in x:
    z = (bin(ord(y)))
    print (z)
```

What I get:

```
0b1101000
0b1100101
0b1101100
0b1101100
0b1101111
```

What I want:

```
[0b1101000, 0b1100101, 0b1101100, 0b1101100, 0b1101111]
```

Comment: replace `print(z)` to `mylist.append(z)`

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
z = [bin(ord(y)) for y in x]
print(z)
```

That is a shortcut for this:

```
z = []
for y in x:
    z.append(bin(ord(y))]
print(z)
```

Comment: Good answer. I still like the old style (w/o the list comprehension) for readability, at least for newbies (like myself).

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. I also feel the same way, it's easier for me to understand when it's written out completely instead of using the shortcut.

Comment: @NucleoNeco: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the greyed-out checkmark below the vote count.  That gives me a reward for solving your problem and removes this question from the unanswered list.